# How to add items to mutableListOf on click?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build an app that displays a list of goats for a personal project. So far, it's been going smoothly until I reached the part where I need to implement a "+" button that adds new items to the List.

This is what my list looks like:

```
object DataSource {
    val goats =
        mutableListOf(
            Goats(R.string.red, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 8),
            Goats(R.string.nana, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.sharkie, R.string.alpine, 10)

        )
     }
```

Here is the Composable that deals with the Buttons but the code that uses an if statement with isButtonClicked doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
@Composable
fun GoatsApp(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

    var isButtonClicked by mutableStateOf(false)

    val provider = GoogleFont.Provider(
        providerAuthority = "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        providerPackage = "com.google.android.gms",
        certificates = R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs

    )
    val fontName = GoogleFont("Lato")

    val fontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(googleFont = fontName, fontProvider = provider)
    )
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxHeight(0.90f)) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { isButtonClicked = true },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Text(text = "+")
            }
            Text(
                text = "Does",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(12.dp),
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
            )


        }
        Row {
            GoatList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { isButtonClicked = true },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Text(text = "+")
            }
            Text(
                text = "Bucks",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(12.dp),
                fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontFamily = fontFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
            )
        }

        GoatList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

        if(isButtonClicked) {
            goats.add(Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 9)) }

    }


}
```

This is how the list is displayed and it automatically displays all the items inside it.

```
    @Composable
fun GoatList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(goats) { allGoats ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = allGoats, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you please put the code where you are created goats object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose, you should not store any state outside of Composables or ViewModels. So the way you defined your `object DataSource` is not a good practice.

You should instead store your list in a Composable and pass it on to the child Composables that need it. By using [`mutableStateListOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()), you can create a List where Jetpack Compose can detect when you add a new item, and recompose then.

A typical approach in Jetpack Compose would look like this:

```
@Composable
fun GoatsApp(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

    val goatList: List<Goats> = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            Goats(R.string.red, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 8),
            Goats(R.string.nana, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.sharkie, R.string.alpine, 10)
        )
    }

    // ...
    Button(
        onClick = { 
            goatList.add(Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 9))
        },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(text = "+")
    }

    // ...
 
    GoatList(goats = goatList)
}
```

Then update your `GoatList` Composable as follows:

```
@Composable
fun GoatList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    goats: List<Goats>
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(goats) { aGoat ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = aGoat, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, I've been stumped for a few days over this. Definitely forgot about mutableStateListOf()!

Answer (score 0):

when you add an item the the `goats` data list the composable function is not recomposed since no state has been changed here, you need to pass the goats list as a parameter to the composableFunction `GoatList` so whenever the goats mutable list is changed the compose compiler will trigger recomposition of this function.

although this is not a good architecture, the best practice would be to save your data in `flow` and collect this flow as state and pass it to your composable function.

```
@Composable
fun GoatList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    goats: List<Goats>
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(goats) { allGoats ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = allGoats, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```